# itext 5.1 objects missing

Tags: c#, itext

I updated my `iText` dll from 4.x to 5.x and there's no objects for `Table`, `Cell`, and `HeaderFooter`. Were these deprecated or something? Is there a quick way to convert to newer way? Any insight welcomed.

```
DateTime previousDate = list[0].StartDateTime;
                Table headerTable = new Table(1, 1);
                Cell headerCell = new Cell(list[0].TimeZoneStartDateTime.ToLongDateString());
                headerCell.BackgroundColor = Color.LIGHT_GRAY;
                headerTable.AddCell(headerCell);
                headerTable.Padding = 3;
                headerTable.Width = 100;
                headerTable.SetAlignment("Left");
```

Comment: Is this the HeaderFooter you mean: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2598917/itextsharp-is-missing-headerfooter-class ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfPTable` and `iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfPCell`.

Here's an [example](http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/86/iTextSharp-Introducing-Tables) of how to use them.