# MVC iTextSharp Header and Footer c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, itext

I am using MVC2, header and footer worked well with iTextSharp 4.1.6, however it didn't with 5.2.  Here is my code:

```
    public FileStreamResult GridPDF()
            {
                MemoryStream workStream = new MemoryStream();

                //the document
                Document document = new Document();


                PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, workStream);//fs);


                document.Open();


                iTextSharp.text.Font font5 = iTextSharp.text.FontFactory.GetFont("Arial", 10);
                iTextSharp.text.Font font6 = iTextSharp.text.FontFactory.GetFont("Arial", 18);
                             //HeaderFooter header = new HeaderFooter(new Phrase(BPheader, FontFactory.GetFont("Arial", 8, Font.BOLD)), false);
            //header.Border = Rectangle.BOTTOM_BORDER;
            ////header.GrayFill=(Color.GRAY);
            //document.Header = header;

            //HeaderFooter footer = new HeaderFooter(new Phrase("Page: ", FontFactory.GetFont("Arial", 8, Font.ITALIC)), true);
            //footer.Border = Rectangle.TOP_BORDER;
            //document.Footer = footer;
                PdfPTable tableh = new PdfPTable(1);
                PdfPCell cellh = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("", FontFactory.GetFont("Arial", 10)));
                cellh.Colspan = 1;
                tableh.HorizontalAlignment = 0;
                tableh.WidthPercentage = 100;
                cellh.BorderWidth = 3;
                cellh.Padding = 0;
                Image image = Image.GetInstance(Server.MapPath("~/Content/images/logo_small.png"));
                //  image.Alignment = 6; // iTextSharp.text.Image.ALIGN_RIGHT;
                image.ScalePercent(40f); // change it's size
                image.SetAbsolutePosition(500, 750);
                document.Add(image);

                Paragraph p = new Paragraph("Certificate", font6);
                p.Alignment = 1;
                document.Add(p);
                tableh.DefaultCell.Border = Rectangle.TOP_BORDER;
                tableh.DefaultCell.Border = Rectangle.BOTTOM_BORDER;
                tableh.AddCell(cellh);

                //close the document
                document.Close();
                //prepare output stream
                byte[] byteInfo = workStream.ToArray();
                SendPdfToBrowser(byteInfo);
                r

eturn null;
        }
```

Any suggestions!!  Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think you are going to need to be more specific other than 'it no longer works'.  Does it not compile?  Does the PDF look wrong?  Just trying to help you get some better answers.

Comment: What is the compilation error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I know your issue, the HeaderFooter property in iTextSharp was removed in version 5+.  [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2598917/itextsharp-is-missing-headerfooter-class) should help get you on your way.  Basically, you will need to use the PageEvents class to add your header and footer.

Create a class that inherits from PdfPageEventHelper and implement its members.  You only really need OnStartPage for your header and OnEndPage for your footer.  During PDF creation, iTextSharp will fire each of those methods for every page in your PDF.

Additionally, [here is a more thorough example](http://www.mazsoft.com/blog/post/2008/04/30/Code-sample-for-using-iTextSharp-PDF-library.aspx) (in C#).

Comment: Thanks Tommy, the second link is useful.