# How to add header and footer in all page of pdf using iTextsharp version 5.2.0 in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, pdf-generation, itext

I am creating a pdf file using itextsharp. I want to add header and footer for each page in the pdf document. Can anyone tell me how can I do this?

I am using itext 5.2.0 In this, I am unable to find the option to use HeadeFooter class, which is available in the earlier versions.

Thanks in advance..

Comment: Be careful when you do tagging technologies to your question. You can't use all the **C#** versions in one application :) have you looked at this before **http://itextpdf.com/book/chapter.php?id=4**

Comment: more information here -- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2598917/itextsharp-is-missing-headerfooter-class or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2321526/pdfptable-as-a-header-in-itextsharp

Answer (score 7):

Please use this code.

```
public partial class Footer : PdfPageEventHelper
{
    public override void OnEndPage(PdfWriter writer, Document doc)
    {
       Paragraph footer= new Paragraph("THANK YOU", FontFactory.GetFont(FontFactory.TIMES, 10, iTextSharp.text.Font.NORMAL));
       footer.Alignment = Element.ALIGN_RIGHT;
       PdfPTable footerTbl = new PdfPTable(1);
       footerTbl.TotalWidth = 300;
       footerTbl.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER;

       PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell(footer);
       cell.Border = 0;
       cell.PaddingLeft = 10;

       footerTbl.AddCell(cell);
       footerTbl.WriteSelectedRows(0, -1, 415, 30, writer.DirectContent);
    }
}
```

please check my blog for more details
http://gopalkaroli.blogspot.in/2011/11/how-to-add-header-and-footer-on-pdf.html

https://gopalkaroli.wordpress.com/2011/11/12/how-to-add-header-and-footer-on-pdf-file-using-itextsharp-5-1/

Answer (score -1):

For iTextSharp version 5+, Header/Footer property has been removed. Now this can be done by us `PageEventHandler` class. Though it's not strait forward now but the upside is that now you can add more than just plan text in header and footer. [Please check this link](http://www.mazsoft.com/blog/post/2008/04/30/Code-sample-for-using-iTextSharp-PDF-library.aspx) for complete workout of header/footer and more in iTextSharp.